# Cypress e2e test hits real API even though I am stubbing it

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, cypress

I have a cypress test that visits my app's homepage:

```
it('visits homepage', function() {
  cy.visit('http://localhost:3333'); 
});
```

On my homepage, there are two API calls that are triggered, and I want to stub those out so I can test different configurations based on API calls. The page will look different depending on the data I receive from the API.

My beforeEach looks like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.server();

    cy.route(
      'GET',
      'https://myrealapi.com/blah/settings.json?params=abc',
      'fixture:my_fixture_filename_1.json'
    );

    cy.route(
      'GET',
      'https://myrealapi.com/blah/categories.json?params=abc',
      'fixture:my_fixture_filename_2.json'
    );
  });
```

When I run the test in my test runner, it shows the outputs as being not-stubbed:

```
(XHR)
GET 200 /blah/settings.json?params=abc
(XHR)
GET 200 /sockjs-node/info?t=1572007186366
(XHR)
GET 200 /blah/categories.json?params=abc
```

I know it's not being read from my fixtures file because I changed some values and the visual didn't update, nor did the returned data in the API call itself (via the network tab).

Have I set up something wrongly here?

Note the calls are of type fetch but I've used a workaround suggested by Cypress to turn them into XHR's

Comment: Have you checked that that routes appears in Routes tub in Cypress debugger ? As I understand Cypress is not detecting that XHR calls. Try to change your routes definition. Mabe something like that `cy.route('**/blah/settings.json*')`.

Comment: Are you sure those XHRs are hitting the prod server on `myrealapi.com`, and not your local one?